# How do I setup an Azure DevOps Pipeline for SSDT project?

Tags: azure-devops, sql-server-data-tools

How do I setup an Azure DevOps Pipeline for SSDT projects? When I try the built-in templates for .NET Core, I get this error message:

2018-11-29T19:04:33.6287133Z D:\a\1\s\XXX\XXXDB.sqlproj : warning NU1503: Skipping restore for project 'D:\a\1\s\XXX\XXXDB.sqlproj'. The project file may be invalid or missing targets required for restore. [D:\a\1\s\Krystal.sln]

2018-11-29T19:05:36.8178997Z D:\a\1\s\XXXDB\XXXDB.sqlproj(60,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.402\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\SSDT\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

Comment: What does your build definition look like? Are you using a private agent or the hosted agent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've seen this before. The out-of-the-box .NET Core template does not work for SSDT projects -- you have to use Visual Studio Build and point it to the solution file. `dotnet build` does not work for SSDT projects.

Comment: I ended up using the .NET Framework build, which does support both SSDT and .NET Core.